# Laravel using GroupBy and getting the latest entry

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am currently using `groupBy('conv_id')` to group rows from a table called `messages` to a conversation.

Now all the returned results will be a unique `conv_id`, though the unique row is not the latest one but the first one created.

Using `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')` doesn't do much, how would i query for the latest rows?

**The query i am using right now:**

```
$this->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('receiver', '=', $id)->orWhere('sender', '=', $id)->groupBy('conv_id')->select('conv_id', 'created_at')->get()->toArray();
```

**The table looks like this:**

ID | SENDER | RECEIVER | UPDATED_AT | CREATED_AT | CONV_ID

Answer (score 0):

I think, tf you use

```
Message::where('receiver', '=', $id)
->orWhere('sender', '=', $id)
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->select('conv_id', 'created_at')->take(1)->get();
```

Then this will return the last entry/row according to `created_at` matched by `where` clause.